# How to mark values while keep count each time we see a value?

Tags: python, pandas, list, time-series

Does anyone know a way to count values while annotating them?
For example.

We have a reparative state with 3 different values. A, B, C.
We want to count how many times we saw state A but values A are different length of A's in a column.
We have Column A and want to get column B. So we have time series A, B, C and we want to count time wise that A is 1 then B is 1 and C is 1 but when we again see A is 2 and B is 2 and C is 2 and the A again is 3 and so on... (The order is always the same first A then B then C and again A...)

Any ideas?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 3 |

Tried to get a loop but don't know how to count the state.

Comment: So basically you are asking for unique rows with each number having all 3 letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(count)

df['Column B new'] = df.groupby((df['Column A'] != df['Column A'].shift()).cumsum())['Column A'].transform(lambda x: next(d[x.iat[0]]) + 1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Column A  Column B  Column B new
0         A         1             1
1         A         1             1
2         A         1             1
3         B         1             1
4         B         1             1
5         C         1             1
6         A         2             2
7         B         2             2
8         C         2             2
9         A         3             3
10        A         3             3
11        A         3             3
12        A         3             3
13        A         3             3
14        A         3             3
15        B         3             3
16        B         3             3
17        B         3             3
18        C         3             3
19        C         3             3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one way to do it :

```
N = len(df["Column A"].unique())
​
# is the current ts equal to the previous ? if so, cumsum
cs = df["Column A"].ne(df["Column A"].shift().bfill()).cumsum() 
​
df["Column B"] = (cs // N + 1).astype(int)
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)
​​
   Column A  Column B
0         A         1
1         A         1
2         A         1
3         B         1
4         B         1
5         C         1
6         A         2
7         B         2
8         C         2
9         A         3
10        A         3
11        A         3
12        A         3
13        A         3
14        A         3
15        B         3
16        B         3
17        B         3
18        C         3
19        C         3
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach without any modules. A `for` loop iterates through each value in `column_a`. The `counter` variable is incremented only if the current value is `'A'` and the previous value is not `'A'`. This ensures that the counter is only incremented once when a new group of `'A','B','C'` begins. The current value of counter is appended to `column_b` for each iteration. Finally, the value of `prev_value` is updated to the current value for the next iteration.

```
column_b = []
counter, prev_value = 0, ''
for value in column_a:
    counter += value == 'A' and prev_value != 'A'
    column_b.append(counter)
    prev_value = value
```

```
print(column_b)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```